# broadcasting webcam to multiple subscriber using jsf+primefaces push

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, atmosphere

What I want is broadcasting webcam with audio to multiple people on a webpage . I am familiar with jsf2.0 and primefaces5.0 , I am using primefaces utilities and glassfish 4.0 for servlet container. Where should I start ? Is there any way to make video using webcam and live stream to subcribers(users)?
Because i am making a website where teachers deliver online classes via video streaming using webcam to students.
 Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: you can't. For several reasons:

- PF cannot capture live video (data)
- PF cannot stream live video (data) that is live captured
- Websockets video is not supported in all  browsers.

So you'd better look for a different solution for now

Comment: if you have any solution then please tell??

Comment: www.webex.com comes to mind. Or www.skype.com but there may be free alternatives to.  Or even ones you can host yourself.  But google has enough info on that

Comment: i know many alternatives, but its my degree project module where online classes are deliver any api you know which can help me?